# How to insert into column name from other table where foreign key links?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have two tables
employees table
department table

the emp_id is in both tables.

I want to insert into department_table (dep_emp_name) values emp_name where department_table.emp_id = employees.emp_id;

unfortunately it's not working.

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT_TABLE (DEPT_EMP_NAME)
SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE EMPLOYEES.EMP_ID = DEPARTMENT.EMP_ID;
END;
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, expected results, actual results, and any specific errors you may be encountering.

Comment: @HepC added to the edit my friend

Comment: It says DEPARTMENT.EMP_ID is an invalid identifier

Comment: Please include the definitions of the two tables. Usually when you insert a row you specify more than one column.

Answer (score 2):

You are not joining `EMPLOYEES` table with `DEPARTMENT` table correctly. Use this:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT_TABLE (DEPT_EMP_NAME)
      SELECT EE.EMP_NAME
        FROM EMPLOYEES EE
        inner join DEPARTMENT_TABLE DT
        on EE.EMP_ID = DT.EMP_ID;
END;
```